# Why is my Overriden Field is not taking in effect, on CRActivityMaint

Tags: acumatica

I might seem lost, but I feel that my code is correct but it does not work. I implemented my own PXStringListAttribute, thus removing the base Attribute of existing PXStringListAttribute, but it seems not working.

```
[PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(ActivityStatusListAttribute))]
[CustomStatusApproval]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="test")]
protected virtual void CRActivity_TimeActivity_ApprovalStatus_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you are trying to customize is PMTimeActivity.ApprovalStatus so your cache attached method name is not pointing to the correct reference to override the attributes.

Viewing the properties of the field you can see the dac and field you should use:

[image]

This results in the cache attached method name of *PMTimeActivity_ApprovalStatus_CacheAttached* (using the naming convention of *DataClass_DataField_CacheAttached*)

Here is a working example:

```
public class CRActivityMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.EP.CRActivityMaint>
{
    [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute))]
    [PXStringList(new[]
            {
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.Draft,
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.Open,
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.InProcess,
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.Completed,
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.Approved,
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.Rejected,
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.Canceled,
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.PendingApproval,
                PX.Objects.CR.ActivityStatusListAttribute.Released,
                "T1",
                "T2"
            },
            new[]
            {
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.Draft,
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.Open,
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.InProcess,
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.Completed,
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.Approved,
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.Rejected,
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.Canceled,
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.Balanced,
                PX.Objects.EP.Messages.Released,
                "TEST1",
                "TEST2"
            })]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Some Test")]
    protected virtual void PMTimeActivity_ApprovalStatus_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]